# Gmail Android app can't correctly display html email

Tags: android, mobile, gmail, html-email

I'm trying to send html emails to gmail accounts only. I'm using RocketWay's Notify templates (http://themeforest.net/item/-notify-notification-email-themebuilder-access/8143225). The problem is, that when I open this email in Gmail Android app, overall design of email is somehow destroyed.

In browser, both desktop and mobile version looks good. In Gmail, browser edition is displaying everything correctly, but in Gmail Android app, everything is messy.

I've already used inline css converter, as I found it may help, but it didn't change anything.

Maybe it has something to do with "Mobile Wrapper", but I'm not sure, because HTML is not my piece of cake.

Here's my code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;"/>
    <title>Title</title>
    <!-- @media only screen and (max-width: 640px) 
           {*/
           -->
    <!--

@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) 
           {
           -->
    <!-- Notification 6 -->
  </head>
  <body style="width: 100%;height: 100%;background-color: #fff;margin: 0;padding: 0;-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased">
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" class="full2" bgcolor="#303030" style="background-color: rgb(48, 48, 48);">
      <tr><td style="background-image: url(background.jpg);-webkit-background-size: cover;-moz-background-size: cover;-o-background-size: cover;background-size: cover;background-position: center center;background-repeat: no-repeat;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none" id="not6">


            <!-- Mobile Wrapper -->
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" class="mobile2"><tr><td width="100%" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: none">

                        <div class="sortable_inner ui-sortable" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: none">
                        <!-- Space -->
                        <table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" class="full" object="drag-module-small"><tr><td width="100%" height="50" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: none"/>
                            </tr></table><!-- End Space --><!-- Space --><table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" class="full" object="drag-module-small"><tr><td width="100%" height="50" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: none"/>
                            </tr></table><!-- End Space --><!-- Start Top --><table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" class="mobile2" bgcolor="#3f51b5" style="border-top-left-radius: 5px; border-top-right-radius: 5px; background-color: rgb(63, 81, 181);" object="drag-module-small"><tr><td width="100%" valign="middle" class="image75" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: none">

                                    <!-- Header Text --> 
                                    <table width="540" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" style="text-align: center; border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;" class="fullCenter2"><tr><td width="100%" height="30" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: none"/>
                                        </tr><tr><td width="100%" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: none"><span><img editable="true" src="icon.png" width="75" alt="" border="0" style="width: 75px;height: auto"/></span></td>
                                        </tr><tr><td width="100%" height="30" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: none"/>
                                        </tr></table></td>
                            </tr></table><table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" class="mobile2" bgcolor="#ffffff" object="drag-module-small" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><tr><td width="100%" valign="middle" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: none">

                                    <table width="540" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" style="text-align: center; border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;" class="fullCenter2"><tr><td width="100%" height="30" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: none"/>
                                        </tr></table></td>
                            </tr></table><table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" class="mobile2" bgcolor="#ffffff" object="drag-module-small" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><tr><td width="100%" valign="middle" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: none">

                                    <table width="540" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" style="text-align: center; border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;" class="fullCenter2"><tr><td valign="middle" width="100%" style="text-align: left;font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size: 23px;color: rgb(63, 67, 69);line-height: 30px;font-weight: 100;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none">
                                                <!--[if !mso]><!--><span style="font-family: 'proxima_novathin', Helvetica; font-weight: normal;"><!--<![endif]--><singleline>Hi Stacey, </singleline><!--[if !mso]><!--></span><!--<![endif]-->
                                            </td>
                                        </tr></table></td>
                            </tr></table><table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" class="mobile2" bgcolor="#ffffff" object="drag-module-small" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><tr><td width="100%" valign="middle" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: none">

                                    <table width="540" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" style="text-align: center; border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;" class="fullCenter2"><tr><td width="100%" height="30" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: none"/>
                                        </tr></table></td>
                            </tr></table><table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" class="mobile2" bgcolor="#ffffff" object="drag-module-small" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><tr><td width="100%" valign="middle" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: none">

                                    <table width="540" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" style="text-align: center; border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;" class="fullCenter2"><tr><td valign="middle" width="100%" style="text-align: left;font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size: 14px;color: rgb(63, 67, 69);line-height: 24px;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none">
                                                <!--[if !mso]><!--><span style="font-family: 'proxima_nova_rgregular', Helvetica; font-weight: normal;"><!--<![endif]--><singleline>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer non condimentum purus, in cursus elit. Nunc magna lectus, feugiat et lectus eget, tempor posuere libero. Curabitur dignissim aliquam urna eu aliquam. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum eget luctus magna. Sed non odio lorem. Donec massa dui, euismod at elementum vitae, dapibus eu mauris. </singleline><!--[if !mso]><!--></span><!--<![endif]-->
                                            </td>
                                        </tr></table></td>
                            </tr></table><table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" class="mobile2" bgcolor="#ffffff" object="drag-module-small" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><tr><td width="100%" valign="middle" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: none">

                                    <table width="540" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" style="text-align: center; border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;" class="fullCenter2"><tr><td width="100%" height="40" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: none"/>
                                        </tr></table></td>
                            </tr></table><!----------------- Button Center -----------------><table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" class="mobile2" bgcolor="#ffffff" object="drag-module-small" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><tr><td width="100%" valign="middle" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: none">

                                    <table width="540" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" style="text-align: center; border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;" class="fullCenter2"><tr><td style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: none">
                                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left"><tr><td align="center" height="45" bgcolor="#3f51b5" style="border-top-left-radius: 5px;border-top-right-radius: 5px;border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;padding-left: 30px;padding-right: 30px;font-weight: bold;font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;color: rgb(255, 255, 255);background-color: rgb(63, 81, 181);-webkit-text-size-adjust: none">
                                                            <multiline><!--[if !mso]><!--><span style="font-family: 'proxima_nova_rgbold', Helvetica; font-weight: normal;"><!--<![endif]-->
                                                                <a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.matusmak.leonardo" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);font-size: 15px;text-decoration: none;line-height: 34px;width: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none">Lorem ipsum!</a>
                                                            <!--[if !mso]><!--></span><!--<![endif]--></multiline></td> 
                                                    </tr></table></td>
                                        </tr></table></td>
                            </tr></table><!----------------- End Button Center -----------------><table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" class="mobile2" bgcolor="#ffffff" object="drag-module-small" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><tr><td width="100%" valign="middle" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: none">

                                    <table width="540" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" style="text-align: center; border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;" class="fullCenter2"><tr><td width="100%" height="35" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: none"/>
                                        </tr></table></td>
                            </tr></table><table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" class="mobile2" bgcolor="#ffffff" object="drag-module-small" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><tr><td width="100%" valign="middle" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: none">

                                    <table width="540" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" style="text-align: center; border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;" class="fullCenter2"><tr><td valign="middle" width="100%" style="text-align: left;font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size: 14px;color: rgb(63, 67, 69);line-height: 24px;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none">
                                                <!--[if !mso]><!--><span style="font-family: 'proxima_nova_rgregular', Helvetica; font-weight: normal;"><!--<![endif]--><multiline>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
                                                <br/><br/>
                                                Thank you!
                                                <br/>
                                                I'm not working correctly

                                                </multiline><!--[if !mso]><!--></span><!--<![endif]-->
                                            </td>
                                        </tr></table></td>
                            </tr></table><table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" class="mobile2" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="border-bottom-left-radius: 5px; border-bottom-right-radius: 5px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);" object="drag-module-small"><tr><td width="100%" valign="middle" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: none">

                                    <table width="540" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" style="text-align: center; border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;" class="fullCenter2"><tr><td width="100%" height="50" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: none"/>
                                        </tr></table></td>
                            </tr></table><table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" class="full2" object="drag-module-small"><tr><td width="100%" height="30" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: none"/>
                            </tr></table><table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" class="mobile2" object="drag-module-small"><tr><td valign="middle" width="100%" style="text-align: left;font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size: 13px;color: rgb(255, 255, 255);line-height: 24px;font-style: italic;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none">
                                    <!--[if !mso]><!--><span style="font-family: 'proxima_nova_rgregular', Helvetica; font-weight: normal;"><!--<![endif]-->Text <!--<![endif]--></span><!--[if !mso]><!-->

                                    <!--[if !mso]><!--><span style="font-family: 'proxima_nova_rgregular', Helvetica;"><!--<![endif]--><unsubscribe style="text-decoration: none; color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"/><!--[if !mso]><!--></span><!--<![endif]-->
                                </td>
                            </tr></table><table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" class="mobile2" object="drag-module-small"><tr><td width="100%" height="30" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: none"/>
                            </tr></table><table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" class="mobile2" object="drag-module-small"><tr><td width="100%" height="29" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: none"/>
                            </tr><tr><td width="100%" height="1" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: none"/>
                            </tr></table></div>

                    </td>
                </tr></table></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <!-- End Notification 6 -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Gmail on Android likes to make your email responsive for you by re-sizing elements. A workaround is adding min-width:600px; to an element or cell that is full width.

For instance, the td on line 27 is a full width cell, so I have added the min-width css to that. It renders fine after that...

I'm not sure if you received the template in such disarray but it is poorly coded. Apologies if this was you, I just figured you should know in case of further issues...

I would also suggest an HTML formatter to clean up your code: http://www.freeformatter.com/html-formatter.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;"/>
    <title>Title</title>
    <!-- @media only screen and (max-width: 640px) 
        {*/
        -->
    <!--
        @media only screen and (max-width: 479px) 
                   {
                   -->
    <!-- Notification 6 -->
</head>
<body style="width: 100%;height: 100%;background-color: #fff;margin: 0;padding: 0;-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased">
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" class="full2" bgcolor="#303030" style="background-color: rgb(48, 48, 48);">
        <tr>
            <td style="background-image: url(background.jpg);-webkit-background-size: cover;-moz-background-size: cover;-o-background-size: cover;background-size: cover;background-position: center center;background-repeat: no-repeat;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none" id="not6">
                <!-- Mobile Wrapper -->
                <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" class="mobile2">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="100%" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: none">
                            <div class="sortable_inner ui-sortable" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: none">
                                <!-- Space -->
                                <table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" class="full" object="drag-module-small">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td width="100%" height="50" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: none; min-width:600px;" />
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                                <!-- End Space --><!-- Space -->
                                <table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" class="full" object="drag-module-small">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td width="100%" height="50" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: none"/>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                                <!-- End Space --><!-- Start Top -->
                                <table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" class="mobile2" bgcolor="#3f51b5" style="border-top-left-radius: 5px; border-top-right-radius: 5px; background-color: rgb(63, 81, 181);" object="drag-module-small">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td width="100%" valign="middle" class="image75" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: none">
                                            <!-- Header Text --> 
                                            <table width="540" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" style="text-align: center; border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;" class="fullCenter2">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td width="100%" height="30" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: none"/>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td width="100%" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: none"><span><img editable="true" src="icon.png" width="75" alt="" border="0" style="width: 75px;height: auto"/></span></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td width="100%" height="30" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: none"/>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                                <table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" class="mobile2" bgcolor="#ffffff" object="drag-module-small" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td width="100%" valign="middle" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: none">
                                            <table width="540" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" style="text-align: center; border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;" class="fullCenter2">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td width="100%" height="30" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: none"/>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                                <table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" class="mobile2" bgcolor="#ffffff" object="drag-module-small" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td width="100%" valign="middle" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: none">
                                            <table width="540" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" style="text-align: center; border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;" class="fullCenter2">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td valign="middle" width="100%" style="text-align: left;font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size: 23px;color: rgb(63, 67, 69);line-height: 30px;font-weight: 100;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none">
                                                        <!--[if !mso]><!-->
                                                        <span style="font-family: 'proxima_novathin', Helvetica; font-weight: normal;">
                                                            <!--<![endif]-->
                                                            <singleline>Hi Stacey, </singleline>
                                                            <!--[if !mso]><!-->
                                                        </span>
                                                        <!--<![endif]-->
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                                <table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" class="mobile2" bgcolor="#ffffff" object="drag-module-small" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td width="100%" valign="middle" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: none">
                                            <table width="540" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" style="text-align: center; border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;" class="fullCenter2">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td width="100%" height="30" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: none"/>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                                <table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" class="mobile2" bgcolor="#ffffff" object="drag-module-small" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td width="100%" valign="middle" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: none">
                                            <table width="540" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" style="text-align: center; border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;" class="fullCenter2">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td valign="middle" width="100%" style="text-align: left;font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size: 14px;color: rgb(63, 67, 69);line-height: 24px;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none">
                                                        <!--[if !mso]><!-->
                                                        <span style="font-family: 'proxima_nova_rgregular', Helvetica; font-weight: normal;">
                                                            <!--<![endif]-->
                                                            <singleline>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer non condimentum purus, in cursus elit. Nunc magna lectus, feugiat et lectus eget, tempor posuere libero. Curabitur dignissim aliquam urna eu aliquam. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum eget luctus magna. Sed non odio lorem. Donec massa dui, euismod at elementum vitae, dapibus eu mauris. </singleline>
                                                            <!--[if !mso]><!-->
                                                        </span>
                                                        <!--<![endif]-->
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                                <table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" class="mobile2" bgcolor="#ffffff" object="drag-module-small" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td width="100%" valign="middle" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: none">
                                            <table width="540" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" style="text-align: center; border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;" class="fullCenter2">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td width="100%" height="40" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: none"/>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                                <!----------------- Button Center ----------------->
                                <table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" class="mobile2" bgcolor="#ffffff" object="drag-module-small" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td width="100%" valign="middle" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: none">
                                            <table width="540" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" style="text-align: center; border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;" class="fullCenter2">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: none">
                                                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left">
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td align="center" height="45" bgcolor="#3f51b5" style="border-top-left-radius: 5px;border-top-right-radius: 5px;border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;padding-left: 30px;padding-right: 30px;font-weight: bold;font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;color: rgb(255, 255, 255);background-color: rgb(63, 81, 181);-webkit-text-size-adjust: none">
                                                                    <multiline>
                                                                        <!--[if !mso]><!-->
                                                                        <span style="font-family: 'proxima_nova_rgbold', Helvetica; font-weight: normal;">
                                                                            <!--<![endif]-->
                                                                            <a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.matusmak.leonardo" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);font-size: 15px;text-decoration: none;line-height: 34px;width: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none">Lorem ipsum!</a>
                                                                            <!--[if !mso]><!-->
                                                                        </span>
                                                                        <!--<![endif]-->
                                                                    </multiline>
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </table>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                                <!----------------- End Button Center ----------------->
                                <table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" class="mobile2" bgcolor="#ffffff" object="drag-module-small" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td width="100%" valign="middle" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: none">
                                            <table width="540" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" style="text-align: center; border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;" class="fullCenter2">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td width="100%" height="35" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: none"/>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                                <table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" class="mobile2" bgcolor="#ffffff" object="drag-module-small" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td width="100%" valign="middle" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: none">
                                            <table width="540" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" style="text-align: center; border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;" class="fullCenter2">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td valign="middle" width="100%" style="text-align: left;font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size: 14px;color: rgb(63, 67, 69);line-height: 24px;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none">
                                                        <!--[if !mso]><!-->
                                                        <span style="font-family: 'proxima_nova_rgregular', Helvetica; font-weight: normal;">
                                                            <!--<![endif]-->
                                                            <multiline>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
                                                                <br/><br/>
                                                                Thank you!
                                                                <br/>
                                                                I'm not working correctly
                                                            </multiline>
                                                            <!--[if !mso]><!-->
                                                        </span>
                                                        <!--<![endif]-->
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                                <table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" class="mobile2" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="border-bottom-left-radius: 5px; border-bottom-right-radius: 5px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);" object="drag-module-small">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td width="100%" valign="middle" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: none">
                                            <table width="540" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" style="text-align: center; border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;" class="fullCenter2">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td width="100%" height="50" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: none"/>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                                <table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" class="full2" object="drag-module-small">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td width="100%" height="30" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: none"/>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                                <table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" class="mobile2" object="drag-module-small">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td valign="middle" width="100%" style="text-align: left;font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size: 13px;color: rgb(255, 255, 255);line-height: 24px;font-style: italic;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none">
                                            <!--[if !mso]><!-->
                                            <span style="font-family: 'proxima_nova_rgregular', Helvetica; font-weight: normal;">
                                                <!--<![endif]-->Text <!--<![endif]-->
                                            </span>
                                            <!--[if !mso]><!-->
                                            <!--[if !mso]><!-->
                                            <span style="font-family: 'proxima_nova_rgregular', Helvetica;">
                                                <!--<![endif]-->
                                                <unsubscribe style="text-decoration: none; color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"/>
                                                <!--[if !mso]><!-->
                                            </span>
                                            <!--<![endif]-->
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                                <table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" class="mobile2" object="drag-module-small">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td width="100%" height="30" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: none"/>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                                <table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" class="mobile2" object="drag-module-small">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td width="100%" height="29" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: none"/>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td width="100%" height="1" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: none"/>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <!-- End Notification 6 -->
</body>
```

Comment: Your code is working, but when I link images to it, email is then completely blank, not showing anything.... I don't know, I will probably stick to simple mails, this is too complicated for such a simple thing...